# Are createElementNS and setAttributeNS still required?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg, namespaces

The usual answer seems to be name clashes in the namespaces. But I guess people are working on this. Any changes?

Comment: Both SVG and HTML have elements named a with different functionality. How could we ever do away with namespaces given that?

Comment: No, people aren't working on it. XML and the DOM interface are cast in stone. There are better APIs than DOM, (e.g. JDOM2 in the Java space, LINQ on C#, JQuery in Javascript) but DOM itself isn't going to change. As for namespaces in XML, everyone wishes they had been done better, but changing something that's so deeply embedded just isn't going to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @RobertLongson and @Michael Kay. In my case I am using JavaScript etc. `createElement("svg")` would not be (more) ambigous than for example `createElement("div")`. So I can't see the need for `createElementNS`. The parser could obviously fix it.

Comment: @Leo createElement("a") should do what then? Or createElement("script")?

Comment: *"But I guess people are working on this."* - as in, magicians are soon to appear and invent the "do what I mean" computer?

Comment: More specifically: *"`createElement("svg")` would not be (more) ambigous than for example `createElement("div")`"* - No, it would not, if you wanted to create an `<svg>` element that is in no namespace and carries no resemblance to the actual `<svg>` element in the `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace, except for having the same local name. `createElement()` will create elements without namespaces, and HTML is extensible enough to allow custom elements. `<svg>` in no namespace is semantically different from `<svg>` in the SVG namespace, no matter how much you'd argue they should be the same.

Comment: That's a bit like arguing that saying `new SqlConnection()` should be good enough, because *you* know that you meant `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, and everybody is using the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace anyway so it should be implied automatically. The one thing (*"everbody is using it like that anyway"*) and the other thing (*"here's a language-level solution for distinguishing the one `SqlConnection` from the other"*) are orthogonal. Mixing them leads to a diminished language.

Comment: @RobertLongson So you say there are name clashes? I do not know SVG good enough to know that.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, I know they are semantically different. But I am not sure I need to know the details. I am not the parser. Can you create a custom `<div>` element too?

Comment: @Tomalak Of course the people that makes the web browser are magicians. No normal humans can do it.

Comment: That's completely, *utterly* besides the point.

Comment: *"Can you create a custom <div> element too"* - of course, when you give it a namespace. The namespace-less div is taken by HTML. You are free to create as many custom `<div>` as you want elsewhere. (You seem to have trouble with the basic concept of namespaces.)

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, maybe I have problem with namespaces. I thought custom elements could be created without giving a namespace. (I have to have a look at my code. It was years since I created custom elements.)